# How does photoshop blend two images together?

Tags: c++, photoshop, effect

[how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919663/how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together)

somebody could explain how photoshop combine two pictures with DIVIDE mode?
i want to implement this effect in java or c++.

Answer (score 1):

Since multiply is this:

```
#define ChannelBlend_Multiply(A,B)   ((uint8)((A * B) / 255))
```

Divide must be:

```
#define ChannelBlend_Multiply(A,B)   ((uint8)((A / B) * 255))
```

Answer (score 0):

This page on wikipedia should help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Divide.

Pixel operation in blending mode are quiet simple operations.  So you should manage to write code with the explanations on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Take the three images: output and two inputs, and analyze their pixel values. You should be able to work out the formula by fitting samples from the image data data to some equations.  I wouldn't make assumptions that Photoshop's divide blend is. If you like that effect, duplicate that effect.