# Image processing: Soft-Light algorithm like Photoshop

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm a developing soft-light algorithm from scratch for Android base on the docs from Adobe:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/blend_modes.pdf
http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/graphics/shaderClasses/SoftLight.pbk

Can anyone explain for me the algorithm or at least `dst, src, cb, cs`, `sampleNearest()` function and how to calculate them?
Thanks you!

```
input image4 dst;
input image4 src;
output pixel4 result;

void
evaluatePixel()
{
    pixel4 a = sampleNearest(dst,outCoord()); // cb
    pixel4 b = sampleNearest(src,outCoord()); // cs
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919663/how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together) for the blending formula:

```
     ChannelBlend_SoftLight(A,B)  ((uint8)((B < 128)?(2*((A>>1)+64))*((float)B/255):(255-(2*(255-((A>>1)+64))*(float)(255-B)/255))))
```

Your code above calculates the blending for one pixel.

`a, b` are the 2 different pixels, the `aampleNearest` function gets the 2 pixels from the input images.

`dst,src` are the 2 input images.

Comment: I'm trying to blend an image of a flower and a white image as SoftLight and I get a white image as result. In the GIMP or photoshop it works ok... what am I doing wrong?