# PHP/Imagick composite blend multiple images

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, composite

I'm trying to use [PHP/Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) api to implement the effect that the `convert` command (with `ImageMagick`) does. For convenience, I have simplified my question as this:

The result I want to achieve is this:

`convert one.jpg two.jpg three.jpg -compose blend -define compose:args=100,0 -composite result.jpg`

While in the PHP/Imagick api, I can only find the [Imagick::compositeImage()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php) function that can only do `composite` one by one, but not three images together. I have tried to do it firstly composite `one.jpg` with `two.jpg`, and then use the temporary result to composite with `three.jpg`. It turns out that the result is not the same with that of the `convert` command.

So how can I achieve the effect in `result.jpg` with the PHP/Imagick api?

Thanks. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your code, using composite the way u did should work, you must be messing with some argument or imagick handle.

Comment: @kailash19 thank you for your comment. I finally found the way by checking out the source code of imagemagick. Mostly are parameter problem.

Comment: @taijirobot Could you please post the answer to your question? I am having the same problem right now and can't figure it out.

Comment: @JensFischer I guess I had a misunderstanding of blending images. In fact I think blending is always a layer by layer operation. You can check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919663/how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together. As to the argument settings, there is a `setOption` method. Btw, in my question, the compose argument setting is `100,0`, which seems meaningless because it takes 100% from the source image and 0% from the other. For blending images in Imagemagick, please refer to: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#blend