# Photoshop like brush with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to add some blur brush stroke with OpenCV

If I use cv.add or cv.addweighted, I only got half of the red color (look pink),

but I want the red to cover the underlying picture, not blend.

If I use copyto or clone, I can't get the blur edge, so how should I do it ??

[image: Paint Brush]

[image]

Comment: if you don't blend the colours you won't have any blur / soft edge effect as you will either have background or 100% red...

Answer (score 0):

The background of your brush image is black. If you were in photoshop and set that brush layer's blend mode to [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Screen) the red gradient would show through and the black background would become transparent.

Here are a couple of relevant posts:

- [How does photoshop blend two images together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919663/how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together)
- [Trying to translate formula for blending mode](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15789/trying-to-translate-formula-for-blending-mode)

Alternatively, if you're using OpenCV 3.0 you try using [`seamlessClone`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/cloning.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got a trick to do it simply copy the area to a new mat, then draw a circle and blur it on the new mat, and use addWeighted to blend it to the image with whatever alpha I need.

```
Mat roi = myImage.submat(y-20, y+20, x-20, x+20);
Mat mix = roiB.clone();

Imgproc.circle(mix, new Point(20, 20), 12, color, -1);
Core.addWeighted(mix, alpha, roiB, beta, 0.0, mix);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mix, mix, new Size(21, 21), 0);

mix.copyTo(roiB);
```